# Is there any lower bound on DHCP lease time?

Tags: dhcp

Currently I am facing an issue to change the value of the DHCP lease time option in the server and configuring the the client with the same value. I have used dhcp-server package and have put the following entry in the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file in the server for the default lease time.

default-lease-time                  60;

However when I start the dhcp service at the client side, the client still takes 300 seconds as its dhcp lease time value. I have tried to make it work by deleting the  /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases file at the clients side and restart the DHCP server, but it did not help. It always gets 300 seconds as its dhcp lease time value.

What do you think may be the possible cause behind this? Do you think there is any lower bound on the dhcp lease time option value?
N.B. I am aware that setting a DHCP lease as low as 60 seconds does not make much sense from the perspective that a client has to refresh its lease information in at most 60 seconds and this increases the network traffic. But I was experimenting with different configuration parameters and would appreciate if someone can tell me if it is possible to set a DHCP lease time as low as 60 seconds. If not, then why?

Comment: Why in the name of great Googly Moogly are you trying to set a 60 second lease time?!?

Comment: As I said, I was merely experimenting with the parameter and just wanted to see if it works.

Comment: Various wifi accesspoints will give default short leasetimes, as the clients are likely to be gone a few minutes later. Clients that remain will get longer lease-times on renewal. Still, 5 minutes would sound like a somewhat sane minimum leasetime.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum lease time used to be 1 hour (see RFC1541). In more recent versions of the specification, there is no official minimum lease time and the client is supposed to refuse a lease if it doesn't like the lease time. So this client is arguably broken.

Comment: I ran wireshark over the ip allocation process and found that in DHCP Offer, the server itself offers an IP Address Lease Time of 300 seconds (Even though I set it to 60 seconds). So, it is unlikely that the client is broken. Any clue what might go wrong in the server side?
I also researched a bit on RFC 2131 and found that they have removed the restriction on the minimum lease time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set lease time in */etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf* like this

```
default-lease-time 60;
max-lease-time 60;
min-lease-time 60;
```

The default *min-lease-time* is *300s*. The reason why you see 300s in wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

The [DHCP Specification RFC 2131 - which supercedes RFC 1541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131) uses a 4-octet/32-bit value to represent lease time, in seconds - therefore 0 is zero seconds (I'd advise against not using this), 1 is one second and 0xffffffff is infinity - though 0xfffffffe isn't and actually works out to be just under 136.2 years.